# How do I make NetBeans Module reference an external jar in place without copying it to the project folder?

Tags: git, netbeans, version-control, jar, netbeans-platform

I'm building a NetBeans Platform Application (RCP) and reference a number of external jars including JFreeChart.

NetBeans copies the jars from my library folder (where I store jars for use in all my projects, including non-NetBeans projects) into the NetBeans project folder (release/modules/ext) and the jar is added to version control!!!  The jar is then stored in my git repository.

I do not want these external jars stored in my git repository or my project folder.  When I build a release, I would like to include them in the release, but until that moment, I only want the jars in my library folder (/Users/username/local/lib) in my case.

How do I make a NetBeans Module reference the external jar in place without copying it into my project?

Comment: Isn't this the job of Version Control ? add the directory to .gitignore. It won't be checked in. Netbeans probably needs that jar in that location for code completion and classpath reference during compilation, debugging and execution.

Comment: I agree with @ShaggyInjun, this is a version control issue. Make sure you run "Clean" on the project before you commit. This way none of the build artifacts will be included.